# I can not have a Constructor method / prototype that takes multiple integers as arguments? Arduino?

Tags: c++, constructor, arduino

I want to make a my Constructor that need two arguments then use it to make some instances, but I get errors like this.

```
*"Too_Many_Moles:8: error: conversion from 'mole*' to non-scalar type 'mole' requested
           mole mole6 = new mole( 7, 13 );

                                ^
exit status 1                                 
conversion from 'mole*' to non-scalar type 'mole' requested"*
```

***what I am useing***

- Arduino/Genuino Uno chip mega328u
- Arduino IDE V1.6.12
- this should not matter because I just need it to verify

***main.ino file***

```
#include <mole.h>

mole mole1 = new mole( 2, 8  );
mole mole2 = new mole( 3, 9  );
mole mole3 = new mole( 4, 10 );
mole mole4 = new mole( 5, 11 );
mole mole5 = new mole( 6, 12 );
mole mole6 = new mole( 7, 13 );

//I whould also like a array of moles here so I can do something like this.
//moleArray[0].sould_be_up = true;
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
}
```

***mole.h file***

```
#ifndef mole_h
#define mole_h

#include "Arduino.h"

class mole
{
  public:
    mole(int p_out, int p_in);
    void changeMoleSate();
    void resetMole();

    void setUpTimer(int up_timer);
    int  getUpTimer();

    //I think I will move these to that main class 
    //************************
    void decrementUpTimer();
    //************************

    void setRecoveryTimer(int recovery_timer);
    int  getRecoveryTimer();

    //************************
    void decrementRecoveryTimer();
    //************************

    boolean sould_be_up = false;

  private:
    int _up_timer = 0;
    int _recovery_timer = 0;
    int _pin_out;
    int _pin_in;
    // todo
    //void setPinsModes();
};
#endif
```

***mole.cpp file***

```
#include "Arduino.h"
#include "mole.h"

mole::mole(int p_out, int p_in) {
  this._pin_out = p_out;
  this._pin_in  = p_in;
}

// todo
/*void mole::setPinsModes() { 
  pinMode(_pino , OUTPUT);
  pinMode(_pini , INPUT );
}*/

void mole::changeMoleSate() {
  if (sould_be_up == false) {
    digitalWrite(_pino, LOW);
  }
  else {
    digitalWrite(_pini, HIGH);
  }
}

void mole::resetMole() {
  sould_be_up = false;
  _up_timer = 0;
  _recovery_timer = 0;
  digitalWrite(_pino, LOW);
}


void mole::setUpTimer(int up_timer) {
  _up_timer = up_timer;
}

int mole::getUpTimer() {
  return _up_timer;
}

void mole::decrementUpTimer() {
  if (_up_timer > 0) {
    _up_timer--;
  }
}


void mole::setRecoveryTimer(int recovery_timer) {
  _recovery_timer += recovery_timer;
}

int mole::getRecoveryTimer() {
  return _recovery_timer;
}

void mole::decrementRecoveryTimer() {
  if (_recovery_timer > 0) {
    _recovery_timer--;
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason for the `c`-tag or do you just like the letter?

Comment: https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/FAQ    "The Arduino software is also open-source. The source code for the Java environment is released under the GPL and the C/C++ microcontroller libraries are under the LGPL."  so I don't know

Comment: This appears to be a bit of a "false friends" case, assuming you're familiar with Java, and just learning C++.  In Java, non-primitive variables are actually references (similar to C/C++ pointers) to objects on the heap; in C++, a variable is only a pointer if you explicitly declare it as one.  So, `mole mole1` in Java is actually equivalent to `mole* mole1` in C++.  You can either create the objects directly, without `new` (see Pete Becker's answer, below), or change `mole mole1 = new mole( 2, 8  );` and similar lines to `mole* mole1 = new mole( 2, 8  );` (with an asterisk).

Comment: Generally, the former keeps you from having to worry about memory management, so it's usually a better choice.  If you go with the latter, you have to delete it manually when you're done with it, or there'll be a memory leak.  Note, however, that with the former, the object will be destroyed when the scope containing it exits; local variables are destroyed when the function returns, non-static class member variables are destroyed when the containing instance is destroyed, and global variables are destroyed when the program exits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mole mole1 = new mole( 2, 8  );
```

This attempts to create a `mole` object on the free store and save the pointer to that object in `mole1`. That won't work. Just create the `mole1` object directly:

```
mole mole1( 2, 8  );
```